# What is Kurumi's Gender?

Tags: sundome

In *Sundome*, was Kurumi a transsexual boy before? I remember reading that in an early chapter Kurumi revealed that she used to be a boy before to the main character. Also she claimed to have the same father as him, kind of curious don't you think?

Answer (score 3):

Kurumi is a girl, she told the main character that she used to be a boy, but it turned out she was just messing with him.

We can be fairly certain that there was no more to the joke as whilst the main character was stressing out and trying to judge his feelings on the matter, Kurumi had forgotten all about it by the time he approached her again about it.

The claim about sharing a father was similarly false

Answer (score -1):

Those were just jokes to prevent him from cumming/masterbating. Even if you did not understand her jokes, there is other evidence.

Both the doctor and her wife regarded her as a female. She was an actual little girl on the swing set when the doctor first found her.